# Pandas: create plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have dataframe

```
         bank_card  used_at  unique_users  all_time
0         Credit  2015-01           513    2368.0
1         Credit  2015-02           352    1375.0
2         mortgage  2015-01           355    1235.0
3         mortgage  2015-02           394    2147.0
4         mortgage  2015-03           298    1401.0
5         mortgage  2015-04           350    1890.0
```

And I need to build graph. I try to do it and get
[image: graph]
But I need to get `used_at` values at `x` axis.
`all_time` at `y` axis to every type of `bank_card`.

It establish only name of axis `ax.set_xlabel("used_at", fontsize=12)`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the index to `'used_at'`

```
idf = df.set_index('used_at')
```

Result:

```
>>> idf.plot(y='all_time')
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000011D0FDA0>
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: you want both Credit and Mortgage on one plot here you go:

```
>>> idf.groupby('bank_card')['all_time'].plot()
bank_card
Credit      Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
mortgage    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
Name: all_time, dtype: object
>>> plt.legend(loc='best')
<matplotlib.legend.Legend object at 0x0000000011924588>
>>> plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: But how can I get 2 curves to `Credit` and `mortgage` on the one plot?